# How to handle refresh tokens in golang/oauth2 client lib

Tags: go, oauth-2.0

There are few examples of using https://github.com/golang/oauth2 but none of them covers usage of refresh tokens. I've tried few approaches, but i'm still unsatisfied with my results.

Is there any example code, or maybe you know some project at **Github** using `oauth2 lib` to take as example?

Comment: From this gist (https://gist.github.com/jfcote87/89eca3032cd5f9705ba3#file-gistfile1-go-L26-L30) it seems that, yes you should retrieve the token from your database and return it as `*oauth2.Token`. The token struct definition is here: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/token.go#L25-L49 . Links, and further discussion here: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/84

Comment: Also, this may be of interest "Client returns an HTTP client using the provided token. The token will auto-refresh as necessary." from https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Client

Comment: Thank you @Intermernet! I'll test it tonight but right now i see the solution to my problem. While my code looks relatively similar i didn't check for validity of token so first call after expiry always failed.

Comment: It sounds like that is probably the problem. If so, please post it as an answer (preferably along with some simple example code).

Answer (score 33):

You need not bother about refreshing tokens until the time you are storing the `Expiry` parameter. After getting the 'Token' object, store the following in your database:

`token.AccessToken`, `token.RefreshToken`, `token.TokenType` and  `token.Expiry`

while fetching, construct the token object again using the above parameters:

```
token := new(oauth2.Token)
token.AccessToken = {{ From DataBase }}
token.RefreshToken = {{ From DataBase }}
token.Expiry = {{ From DataBase }}
token.TokenType = {{ From DataBase }}
```

and then get your http client:

`config.Client(ctx, token)`

this will handle refreshing the token. Excerpt (more info: [Golang oauth2 client](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Config.Client)):

> Client returns an HTTP client using the provided token. The token will auto-refresh as necessary.

Only downside is, the refreshed access token is not returned. But it works! Google has no restrictions on how many times the refresh token is used.

Comment: You're right. I have come to this code after few tries and it works, more or less. As for updating I guess I'll build my Client struct with some sort of hook.

Comment: Anyway this is a must for my case since server refreshes both accessToken and refreshToken, so i should catch refresh and store it in database immediately.

Comment: hey @Andrew I'm kind of looking to do the same thing, what did you end up doing to store refresh tokens and replace older access tokens?

Comment: There is a discussion on GitHub about that issue: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/84

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the `AccessToken` after a refresh happens (now)?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. These only two statement made it work for me with the oauth2 client
`token := new(oauth2.Token)                                        
 token.RefreshToken = {{ From DataBase }}` Actually the client takes care of refreshing the access token even if it is not specified.

Comment: To get the updated token you can follow this: https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/84#issuecomment-175591180 or this https://github.com/golang/oauth2/issues/84#issuecomment-254576796

Comment: I believe the answer and examples provided by Theraloss are wrong. First of all, the refresh token is often updated when using it, and must be replaced at that time. The old refresh token can no longer be used. The code examples are wrong as they only cover token refreshing when loading it from a cache. The library automatically refreshes the token every now and then when using the http.Client and you'll miss all of those times.